# Update multiple items in ListView

Tags: mysql, sql, listview, sql-update, edit

I have 5 tables joined together.

```
SELECT FormTitle, FormSection ,SubSection, SectionItem 
  FROM Core.Form_Section_SubSection_Item_Rel c
 INNER JOIN Core.FormSection_Lkup l
    ON c.FormSectionID = l.FormSectionID JOIN Core.FormSubSection_Lkup s
    ON c.SubSectionID = s.SubSectionID JOIN Core.SectionItem_Lkup i
    ON c.SectionItemID = i.SectionItemID JOIN Core.Form_Lkup f
    ON c.FormID = f.FormID
```

Is there a way to update FormTitle, FormSection ,SubSection, SectionItem in 1 query statement using the edit in ListView?

Comment: Do `FormTitle`, `FormSection`, `SubSection`, `SectionItem` come from the same table?

Comment: @user1406062 no they do not

Comment: Then, short answer is no. Long answer is to update each table separately.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a view and add a instead of update trigger .
into trigger ,run separated update for each table (using inserted variable)